# Link Paypal Html Script and webhook

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-subscriptions, paypal-webhooks

I am using the Paypal Subscription Button Html and Script  provide by paypal. Now I wanted to link with paypal webhook. I want to track the events like  BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.RENEWED and BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.CANCELLED.

Is this possible without using the App keys? When I created the App , I created with the same paypal-id so, that means my all webhooks in app is going get render when subscription event take place, without attaching any keys with it ?

Anyone there who can solve my query?

Answer (score 0):

In order to receive Webhook events, you need to first subscribe to them.

For information on ways to subscribe to Webhook events for an application, see [the PayPal documentation here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api-basics/notifications/webhooks/rest/#subscribe-to-events).

It can be done via an API call, or via the Developer Dashboard.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But I have read the documentation , the only question is that without using API, Can I connect webhook to my subscription Button Html which paypal gave me? Is this possible ?

Comment: The documentation details how to subscribe to particular webhook events.